# Asp.net 301 Redirect With Multiple QueryString Parameters

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config, query-string

I have url like

```
domain.com/posts/id/title
```

I want to change URL

```
domain.com/title-xxx-id
```

id and title querystring parameters. -xxx- is static.

I had used

```
 <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">

  <match url=".*" />

  <conditions>

    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^olddomain.com$" />

  </conditions>

  <action type="Redirect" url="https://newdomain.com/{R:0}"

       redirectType="Permanent" />

</rule>
```

to domain change but now I need url change in same domain and I have two parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same domain the redirect is even simpler using `URLRewrite (2.x)`. Something like this.

```
  <rule name="friendly" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^post/(.+)/(.+)$" negate="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}-xxx-{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

But in fact you need to send `title-xxx-id` url to a handler to process. You can do it like this (supposing `post` is the controller you use).

```
  <rule name="friendly1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.+)-xxx-(\d+)$" negate="false"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/post?title={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}" appendQueryString="false"/>
  </rule>
```

In fact, both rules can work together.

```
  <rule name="friendly" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^post/(.+)/(.+)$" negate="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}-xxx-{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="friendly1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.+)-xxx-(\d+)$" negate="false"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/post?title={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}" appendQueryString="false"/>
  </rule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I have one more question. After this change I have a new problem. Can you help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628919/asp-net-url-rewrite-rule